How to create a clamshell without sculpting?
(Reposting this question after re-doing my clamshell. If i can be completely honest, I think I messed somewhere this time and it doesnt look as nice as my previous try.)
I'm trying to create a clamshell model similar to the one in the image below, but I'd like to avoid using sculpting. Does anyone have tips or techniques for modelling a detailed clamshell using other methods?
The reason why I'm hesitant with sculpting is because I've not really done this so much in the past.
I'm looking for something with a similar smoothness and shell thickness. It doesn't need to be very realistic; in fact, I'd prefer it to have a blend of cartoon-y and realistic.

This is what I have at the moment after following this video (as you can see, I messed up somewhere and it looks a bit wonky):

Note: I'm not very concerned about the materials at the moment
Edit:


First draw the shape:

Pull the edges to create the relief:

Bevel the edges (1 segment only):

Create these horizontal edge loops:

Activate the Proportional Editing option and pull the central vertices to make the object concave:

Extrude the whole mesh to give it thickness:

Bevel the outter edges:

Give it a Subdivision Surface modifier and shade smooth:


I got a decent shape following your steps, except that I used the mirror modifier to get the left side of the shell. I ended with a strange line in between. Is there a way to get rid of it or would you recommend that I make the whole thing without using the mirror modifier? Thank you once again!!!
I'll make an edit with the screenshot of the line and also the blend file.

You don't need the Mirror, or use it at the beginning but you'll need to apply it when you'll create the vertical bevels

got it, thank you!
